# How To Get System.getProperties() In Apache Flink Jobs

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am running flink standalone cluster that consist of 3 servers. I added "env.java.opts: '-Dmykey=1000'" this settings on my 3 nodes, in this file flink-1.6.0/conf/flink-conf.yaml

When I check java programs, I can see this parameter passed through to my TaskManager and JobManager

```
 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Xms15360M -Xmx15360M -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=8388607T -Dmykey=1000 -Dlog.file=/home/kafka/flink-1.6.0/log/flink-
```

When I try to print out all properties, iterating System.getProperties(), I cannot fetch my custom properties.

I have libraries that uses property files to get external information, I cannot change my libraries, make them use ParameterTools. I did a lot things, but still could not solve this. Is there any advice for me?

Comment: You can try querying the configurations for keys `env.java.opts.jobmanager` and `env.java.opts.taskmanager`. Refer https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/config.html#environment

Comment: @shriyog when I look at the linux processes, I see  -Dmykey=1000. But I cannot get it in my program.

Comment: Did you use the above mentioned keynames for getting values from the configuration map?

Comment: @shriyog When I submit my fat jar, I print out all System.getProperties() values. For example, I can see log.file key and value of it, but I cannot see mykey and value of it.

Comment: I tried it out and it seemed to work for me. Where exactly are you printing the system properties? Please make sure that this happens on the cluster (e.g. in a user code function). If you print it outside of a user function, it will actually be executed on the client.